# how to search for folder name under media - or create one - django

Tags: python, django

I am stuck in this step:

I have an upload function which saves files under `upload` folder under `media` folder. those files will be saved in folders which are also at the same time created by the name of user who is uploading the file. those folders with files will be created under `upload` folder under `media` folder

```
def custom_path(instance, filename):
return '/'.join(['upload',instance.student.user.username,filename])

class Doc(models.Model):
    uploadtime = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, blank=True)
    datei = models.FileField(upload_to=custom_path,default='')
```

now what i want to do is:

1) search for specific folder name
2) if found, look into it - if not found, create one.

How can i get all folder names under given folder? or how can I loop over folders and get their name?

if i do this: `os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname( __file__ ), os.pardir, 'media/upload'))` i am getting the path to `upload` folder. i am a little bit confused not knowing how to search for folder name under this path

any statement will be appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def custom_path(instance, filename):
    path = os.path.join('upload', 'media', slugify(instance.student.user.username))
    try:
        os.path.mkdir(path)
    except OSError:
        # path already exists
        pass
```

Using [`slugify`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/utils/#module-django.utils.text) here in case the username contains some special characters that are not allowed as file name.

`os.path.mkdir` will raise `OSError` if the directory already exists.

Finally, `os.path.join` to correctly create a path and you don't need the filename component, since you are returning a directory path.

Comment: perfect, very nice. do i have to import mkdir from somewhere?

Comment: You need two imports: `import os` and `from django.utils.text import slugify`

Answer (score 1):

One thing you may want to keep in mind is that having a large number of sub-directories under **media/upload** will eventually make access to that directory very, very slow. In my experience, access time starts to deteriorate with about 1000 directories/files under a directory.

If you anticipate that is the case, you may want to modify your design to store your user's files in a DB instead.